# Find the 'average' vector shape?

Tags: algorithm

I have 100 similar shapes (simple vector graphics). How can i find the "average/merged" shape of all 100 instances?

Thank,
you

Comment: What do you mean by "average"? For example, what do you consider the average of (1,2,3), (5,0,0), (0,-12,17) ?

Comment: take the average of each direction and combine them all in a vector?

Comment: Let's say i have a 'rectangle' and 'triangel'. I want to merge this into some kind of 'trapezium'. Both are drawn on the same canvas size.

Comment: you could always intersect the two and consider the resulting shape the "average". not sure that thats in any way meaningful though.

Comment: Maybe lay them out flat on the x-axis, and take the shape formed by taking the average height of the two other shapes? In your case, you'd get sort of a pentagon, I believe.

Comment: fabian, some images as example would clear things out

Answer (score 2):

### Algorithm Proposal

1. Compute the area of each shape {A}.
2. Find the shape {S} with most points {N} (you're going to end up with a N side polygon)
3. Merge {S} with another shape and create the first merged {M} shape. Then merge {M} with each other shape remaining. {M} will be dynamic/rewritten/will change every time it's merged with another shape.

---

**Merge function**: *pseudocode*
Call `Merge({S}, {S2})` first, then call `Merge({M}, {S2})` for the rest of the shapes.

Parameters:
{S1}=the shape with most points;
{S2}=shape to merge with;

```
function Merge({S1}, {S2}):    

FOR EACH {point} of {S1} DO
    {near}=find nearest {S2}{point}
    {size}=( SQRT({S1}{A}) + SQRT({S2}{A}) )/2
    {line}=create line starting at {near}, going to/over {point} of length {size}
    add point in {M} with position at half the {line}
END FOR
RETURN {M}
;
```

**3 initial shapes: rectangle, triangle, 7 side polygon** {S}=green
[image: 3shapes]

**merged green with rectangle** {M}=blue
[image: merge1]

**merged blue with triangle** {M}=yellow <-final result
[image: final]

***Notice: merged shapes not on scale! didn't account for areas!***

Comment: That's what i'm talking about!

Comment: nice! don't forget to reply when implemented, I'd like to see it live

Comment: Which programming language would you recommend for implementation?

Comment: whatever you need. choose the one you're most used to.